# The anti definite integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

Is there such a possibility as defining an anti (definite integral)?

For instance:

$$
S(a,b)=F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)dx
$$

The question is what operation $D$ on $S$ produces $f(x)$:

$$
D[S(a,b)]=f(x)
$$

---

For the simple case of $f(x)=x$, it is pretty obvious that, say $D[b^2-a^2]=x$ because

$$
\int_a^bxdx=b^2-a^2 \implies D[b^2-a^2]=x+C
$$

where $C$ is a constant.

So at the minimum, absent a general procedure, one can map out manually a few cases.

But, how far can one take this; is there a special class of functions for which the anti (definite-integral) can be "well-defined"?

Comment: Your $S$ may be rephrased as a function of a domain of integration: $$ S([a, b])=\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Then the resulting set function $S(\cdot)$ naturally defines a (signed) measure, and then its "density" $f$ will correspond to the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) with respect to the Lebesgue measure: $$f=\frac{\mathrm{d}S}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{Leb}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done. You can have two different integrals with the same value despite coming from entirely different functions.

Comment: How about defining $$D[S(a,b)] =\frac{\mathrm dS}{\mathrm db} \bigg|_{b=x} ?$$

Comment: what if $f(x)$ is discontinous

Comment: @SangchulLee Can you give an example of how your proposal recovers simple cases such as $D[b^2-a^2]=x$?

Comment: In OP's case, it boils down to the ordinary differentiation: If a signed Borel measure $S(\cdot)$ on the real line is specified by $S([a,b])=b^2-a^2$, then it is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. So it admits a Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to the Lebesgue measure. which can be computed by $$\frac{\mathrm{d}S}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{Leb}}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0^+} \frac{S([x,x+\Delta x])}{\Delta x}=2x. $$ In other words, this tells that $$S(\mathrm{d}x) = 2x \, \operatorname{Leb}(\mathrm{d}x). $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $S(a,b)$ is a *number* as is $b^2 - a^2$.  (All definite integrals that exist are numbers.)  This will be a significant problem.  Here are two definite integrals on the same interval with the same value (hence, identical $S(a,b)$).  \begin{align*}
0 &= \int_{-1}^1 0 \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
0 &= \int_{-1}^1 x \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
So, is $D[0]$ supposed to be $0$ or $x$?

There is also a definitional problem.  From "$D[S(a,b)]$", we should recognize that we get a different $D$ for every choice of interval, but that choice of interval is not present in our notation for $D$.  This is fixable, write "$D_{a,b}$".  Then we have
$$  D_{-1,1}[0] = 0  $$
and 
$$  D_{-1,1}[0] = x  \text{.}  $$
So there is still an unresolvable ambiguity.  (If that ambiguity were magically resolved, we could then approach the interesting question of what to do with $D_{a,b}[S(c,d)]$ where the only given relations among $a$,$b$,$c$, and $d$ are $a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$.  No idea where that would go since we haven't magically resolved the ambiguity.)

There's a sneaky trick hiding in your example.  The integral on $[a,b]$ of $x$ is the *number*  $b^2 - a^2$.  But rather than work with a definite integral, we were instead to consider the accumulation function 
$$  f(x) = \int_a^x t \,\mathrm{d}t  $$
where $a$ is a constant and $x$ is a variable.  This isn't a number; it's the function $(1/2)(x^2 - a^2)$.  (You forgot the one-half in your version.)  It **is** feasible to get the integrand back from this accumulation function, just differentiate with respect to $x$.  Notice that the choice of $a$ only vertically shifts the graph, so corresponds to adding a constant vertical offset, which is discarded under differentiation.  So the choice of $a$ does not alter the result of differentiation.

The idea that you can differentiate an accumulation function to retrieve its integrand is (the first half of) the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: Does formulating the question along the lines of "given a function $S:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such as $S[a,b]=b^2-a^2$, find the set of all (continuous) functions $f(x)$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = S[a,b]$. This eliminates all cases where the interval would be $[1,-1]$ and thus the result of the integral is never a number, but an expression.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay :  This does not eliminate **all** cases there the interval would be $[1,-1]$, since $1 \in \Bbb{R}$ and $-1 \in \Bbb{R}$.  Also, you seem to be desperate to make definite integrals not be **definite** integrals.  You are, in fact, constructing the set of all accumulation functions with *variable* $b$ and starting point $a$, so you are not extending past or side-stepping the discussion of accumulation functions in the Answer.

Comment: Im sorry to be annoying, but if we add the requirement that the function $f(x)$ works for all $a$ and for all $b$ then $D[b^2-a^2]$ will produce $f(x)=x$ and not $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay : You are not being careful to discriminate between variables and constants.  If $a$ and $b$ are constants, you cannot avoid the ambiguity that many functions have the same definite integral on the same interval.  If $b$ is a variable and $a$ is a constant (or vice versa), the discussion of accumulation functions and the fundamental theorem of calculus applies.  If $a$ and $b$ are both variables, then $D[b^2 - a^2]$ gives, among infinitely many options, $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x = 0 \\ x,& x \neq 0 \end{cases}$, which are not the same function.  (continues)

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay :  Only in the first case ($a$ and $b$ constants) do you have a definite integral, as you mention repeatedly in the Question.  In the other cases, you have various accumulation functions, which are not definite integrals.